# Package refactoring in Scala

Tags: scala, refactoring, package

What is the best way for package refactoring in Scala, e.g. moving all classes in a given package from lib.component1 to lib.components.component1 .

I tried two approaches with Scala-IDE which don't really work.

1)alt-shift-r on the component1 package - Although all the classes under component1 package are moved to new location, the references in other classes in the project are not updated. Doing it manually is a tedious job.

2)Use 'Move class/object/trait feature from Scala-IDE - It just moves a class from one package to another, not changing the package header of the class which was moved.

Answer (score 0):

The "approved" way is to use the Refactor > Move approach. However, it doesn't work.

The Move approach will mangle the import statements referencing the moved file by inserting in the middle of other statements.

Instead, from your shell, move the file, then edit the package line in the file using an external editor. Go back into the IDE and fix all the references to the file; they should all have an error badge.

Comment: I look for a fully automated appproach, like in Eclipse for Java.  I'm so surprised it still does't work well in Scala. In old times I used to refactor quite a lot in Java.

Comment: Yeah. I reach for the refactor button a lot for Java. Scala's saving grace is the programs are so much smaller.